# How to get anchor details when using CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table with 2 columns (id, childId) with the following data:

- 1, 2
- 2, 4
- 3, 5
- 4, 6
- 5, null
- 6, null

I have the following CTE that gets the records and it works fine.

```
DECLARE @id TABLE (id int, childId int);
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 1, 2;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 2, 4;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 3, 5;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 4, 6;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 5, null;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 6, null;

WITH cte AS  
(
    SELECT id, childId
    FROM @id
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.childId
    FROM @id b
    INNER JOIN cte 
        ON b.id = cte.childId
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

However, I would like to add the anchor details so that the results will look like:

- 1, 2, null
- 2, 4, 1
- 4, 6, 1
- 6, null, 1

So that that 3rd column is the main anchor record.

Is this possible?

Comment: If I run your query, I got this: (1,2), (3,5), (5,NULL), (2,4), (4,6), (6,NULL). It does not coincide with the first two columns you provided.

Comment: @DVT Fixed the CTE and the end results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a thrid column in CTE.

```
declare @mytable table ( id int, childId int );
insert  @mytable
        ( id, childId )
values  ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 2, 4 ),
        ( 3, 5 ),
        ( 4, 6 ),
        ( 5, null ),
        ( 6, null );
declare @id table ( id int );
insert  into @id
        select  1;
insert  into @id
        select  3;

with    cte
          as ( select   id ,
                        childId ,
                        id root
               from     @mytable
               where    id in ( select  id
                                from    @id )
               union all
               select   b.id ,
                        b.childId ,
                        cte.root
               from     @mytable b
                        inner join cte on b.id = cte.childId
             )
    select  *
    from    cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS  
(
    SELECT id, childId, id AS anchorId
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 
        id IN (SELECT id FROM @id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.childId, cte.anchorId
    FROM mytable b
    INNER JOIN cte 
        ON b.id = cte.childId
)
SELECT
    id
    , childId
    , case
        WHEN id = anchorId THEN NULL
        ELSE anchorId
    END as anchorId
FROM cte
```

---

With test code provided:

```
DECLARE @id TABLE (id int, childId int);
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 1, 2;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 2, 4;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 3, 5;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 4, 6;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 5, null;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 6, null;

WITH cte AS  
(
    SELECT id, childId, id AS anchorId
    FROM @id
    WHERE id IN (1,3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.childId, cte.anchorId
    FROM @id b
    INNER JOIN cte 
        ON b.id = cte.childId
)
SELECT
    id
    , childId
    , CASE
        WHEN id = anchorId THEN NULL
        ELSE anchorId
    END AS anchorId
FROM cte
```